# Lucene JSON query syntax

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm trying to query an Elasticsearch-wrapped Lucene index with edge ngrams in it, and cannot make sense of the documentation to figure out how to apply boolean operators to it.  I have this:

```
{
  "query":{
  "bool":{
    "should":[
      {
        "match":{
          "name.partial":"+henry +james"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}}
```

That doesn't work (I get results with henry and without james, and vice versa), and neither do \"henry james\", or henry AND james - I get the same things back no matter what.  How do I get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [query_string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html) query for that. If you use the match query, I think the only thing that you can do is specify the query and the operator to use like this:

```
{
    "match" : {
        "message" : {
            "query" : "this is a test",
            "operator" : "and"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick - still wrapping my brain around how this works.  Thanks!

Comment: elasticsearch rocks! And the query DSL gives you many options, that's why it can be hard to pick the right query :)